# Import Error for Mapper in Eclipse IDE. Mapreduce word count program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to import mapper class into Eclipse IDE. I have imported all the required jar files into Eclipse IDE. It is throwing the following error:

> The class file Mapper contains a signature '(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Contex‌​t;)V' ill-formed at position 74

Please Help

Comment: What hadoop dependencies have you imported ?
Which version of jdk are you using ?

Comment: Hadoop Jars - hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.2.jar,hadoopmapreduceclientcore2.7.2.jar                                             JDK version - 1.8

Comment: Can you share your jdk version ?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"

Comment: Try deleting the referenced library for your project and then re-include your jdk library. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Tried that but didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142140/discussion-between-basil-paul-and-deepan-ram).